# Convert CString usable in Format in C# string

Tags: c#-4.0, mfc

How can I convert a CString (eg. "test %s") in a c# string usable with string.format?

eg.

```
CString outStr;
CString formatstring = "test %s"; // this string came from an external file
CString str = "Some Data";
outStr.Format(formatstring, str); // this works in MFC
// outStr -> "test Some Data"
```

i would like to achieve the same outStr result using c#

```
"test %s"; //the formatted string coming from an external file
           // in c# if I understand well it should be "test {0}
CString str = "Some Data";

outStr.Format(formatstring, str); //in c# this doesn't work
// outStr -> "test %s"
```

hope this can clarify
searching a function or a way to convert also a more complex CString.

Comment: It's unclear to me how the question relates to C++. Could you elaborate?

Comment: MFC/ATL's `CString` and .NET's `System.String` have zero overlap. Please explain what you are really trying to achieve. It's likely that what you have asked for is part of a solution you have in mind, that really isn't.

Comment: In other words: You want to convert a `CString`-style format string to a corresponding .NET `System.String`, that can be used with [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx). You will have to write the conversion routine yourself. Given the plethora of format string placeholder combinations, this is not an easy task. A less painful solution would be to write a C++/CLI module that performs the formatting using a `CString` object, and pass the final string to the .NET code.

Answer (score -1):

The string formatting in C# is called Composite Formatting and is slightly different than C and C++ string formatting. Here is the documentation from Microsoft...

[Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a working C# example that is functionally equivalent to your MFC CString example...

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String formatstring = "test {0}";
        String str = "Some Data";
        String outStr;
        outStr = String.Format(formatstring, str);
        Console.WriteLine(outStr);
    }
```

This example will write "test Some Data" to the console.

Comment: This does not address the question.